# Python3 urllib import is failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

So after trying much to do this on my own and failing due to a syntax error, I tried directly copying a code that was proven to work on another computer just to get the same syntax error. Am I missing some files? What is my issue here?
Here is the code

```
import urllib.request
fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')
for line in fhand:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

The error I constantly see is this:

```
  File "/Users/JongWhoLee/Desktop/python/ex_15.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/_policybase.py", line 7, in <module>
    from email import header
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/header.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/email/quoprimime.py", line 44, in <module>
    from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits
  File "/Users/JongWhoLee/Desktop/python/string.py", line 1
    >>> import string
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there something wrong with my computer or is it just me?

Comment: You have a file called string.py which conflicts with the string module

Comment: As the error message says, your file ``/Users/JongWhoLee/Desktop/python/string.py`` includes invalid code. It *also* shadows the builtin ``string`` module. Remove it to fix the error.

Comment: thank you for your help!